# How to introduce an example?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was writting the following sentence yet I was stopped by the way I have to use to present my examples:

> I had to maintain a classroom management and discipline *for
>   example by */ *by, for example* / *for example through* / *through, for example:*
>
> •    Monitoring Student Attendance and Progression.
>
> •     Delivering scheduled lectures to the assigned classes.

Which way is right or better to introduce my example ?
say my example is:

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of your options, I think best is "...by, for example:".

But I don't like the sentence "maintain a classroom management and discipline", because "maintaining a management" is very vague and unclear.

Also I don't think you should really say "for example" at all here. If you are going to only say those 2 points, just say: "...by monitoring student attendance and progression, and delivering scheduled lectures to the assigned classes.

But if you are going to list more points, then assuming this is for a C.V. or something, you would probably want to list all of your key responsibilities, not just an "example" of them.

My choice would probably be:

**I was responsible for classroom management and discipline. My key tasks were to monitor student attendance and progression, and to deliver scheduled lectures to the assigned classes**

Or

I was responsible for classroom management and discipline. My key tasks were:

- to monitor student attendance and progression
- to deliver scheduled lectures to the assigned classes
- etc..
- etc..

Answer (score 2):

There are many good ways to introduce an example.

> I had to maintain ... discipline **by, for example,** monitoring...
>
> I had to maintain ... discipline. **For example,** I monitored...
>
> I used various methods to maintain discipline, **such as** monitoring attendance and delivering scheduled lectures.

It does not work to immediately say "for example", as in your first sentence, "...discipline for example".